# Why I am getting this error "Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero"?

Tags: java, android, divide-by-zero

How can i stop a values lower than <= 0. and its throw exception.

**Logcat :** [Logcat error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE1r3.jpg)

**RoundKnobButton.java file :**

```
int size = GetJsonData.frequency.size();
        int a = Math.round((float)(360/size));
            int b = 0;
            try {
                Log.i("RoundKnob",".....Try");
                b = Math.round((float)(scaleDegrees/a));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("RoundKnob", ".....catch");
            }
```

**DialScreen.java file :**

```
rv = new RoundKnobButton(this, R.drawable.circle, R.drawable.circle1,
            R.drawable.circle1, m_Inst.Scale(350), m_Inst.Scale(350));
```

So, If anyone know the problem solution or give me the idea to solve this error then tell me.

Comment: What is on line 152 `DialScreen.java`?

Comment: I very much doubt that you really need to provide over 700 lines of code to demonstrate the error. The error (which should be posted as plain text *in the question*) shows that the problem is in line 29 of RoundKnob.java, which is dividing by 0. (That's line 29 of the *real* code, not the code you've provided that doesn't include any imports.) Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: So... much... code...

Comment: Line 152 in DialScreen activity is https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cb06fac5c1129f5b58db9fdec79b0a1c

Comment: I know but my reputation is very low and more that two link required atleast 10 reputation so.

Comment: Why don't you just paste the code **here** when it's only one line?

Comment: Update your input and provide a simple [mcve]. Beyond that: the exception tells you that you divide by zero. What is it that you dont understand about that? You dont link or anything. You put up ALL **relevant** code here; typically including the stack trace. Yes, you are new here. So you please spend some time at the [help] to **learn** how/what to ask here.

Comment: You try to divide by zero in your code, you got the stacktrace, you know where you divide by zero, now you should handle it correctly. I assume it's this line `int a = Math.round((float)(360/size));` and `int size = GetJsonData.frequency.size();` is returning 0.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because i got new way to resolve this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look at this line:

```
int a = Math.round((float)(360/size));
```

And assume that `size==361`.

Since `size` is an `int` we have an integer-division and `360/size` equals `0`. Then you cast it to a `float` resulting in `0.0f`, round it (givin `0.0f`) and assign it to an `int` that's also `0` as a result.

What you probably meant to do is

```
int a = Math.round(((float)360/size));
```

Note the different parentheses...

Comment: when I am changing this int a = Math.round((float)(360/size)); to int a = Math.round(((float)360/size)); at that time also generate  error. if you know the second way tell me please.

Comment: First thing to do is finding the actual value of `size` when the error occurs. You can continue from there....